# Can a non-compact group have a (non-trivial) compact subgroup?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, geometry, mathematical-physics

Yeah, the title says it all. It'll be more helpful if someone could provide with some canonical examples in case of an affirmative answer.

EDIT: Those suggesting the trivial subgroup - my mistake - I was after a non-trivial answer. updated the OP. Thanks!

Comment: Of course. The euclidian group, for example, is non-compact on account of translations, but it contains the rotation group as a subgroup

Comment: Surely the trivial subgroup is always compact? Or expanding on this any finite subgroup?

Comment: "The title says it all" is not the best way to present a problem you want help with.  It invites confusion on the part of your Readers.  The body of the Question is there to allow you to give a detailed setup and context for where you found the problem, what makes it interesting, where you ran into difficulty, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is **yes**.

**Example.** Let $G:=\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{R})$, then $H:=O(n)$ is a compact subgroup of $G$ which is non-compact. Indeed, for all $k\geqslant 1$, $\textrm{diag}(k,1,\ldots,1)\in G$, whence $G$ is non-bounded and therefore non-compact. Besides, by definition $H:=\varphi^{-1}(\{I_n\})$ where:
$$\varphi(A)={}^\intercal AA$$
is continuous as a quadratic form. Hence, $H$ is closed and its bounded by definition, whence compact.

Actually, all maximal compact subgroups of $G$ are conjugates of $H$. Another way to put it, any compact subgroup of $G$ is a conjugates of a subgroup of $H$.

Answer (score 2):

The unit circle of the complex numbers (multiplicative group with $0$ removed) is a compact subgroup.

Similarly, $\{-1,+1\}$ is a compact subgroup of the nonzero real numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a whole family of examples: The matrix groups $\mathrm{SL}(n,\mathbb{C})$, $\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{C})$, $SO(n,\mathbb{C})$, and $\mathrm{Sp}(n,\mathbb{C})$ are all real Lie groups. They are not compact (I think this is pretty easy to see). Each has a maximal compact subgroup though. In order, they are $\mathrm{U}(n)$, the unitary matrices, $\mathrm{SU}(n)$ the special unitary matrices, $\mathrm{SO}(n)$ the special unitary matrices with real entries, and $\mathrm{Sp}(n)$, which is $\mathrm{Sp}(n,\mathbb{C})\cap\mathrm{U}(2n)$.